# C++ проблемы getch putch

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Я хочу организовать ввод пароля, чтобы вместо символа в консоли появлялись звездочка, если нажата клавиша Enter ввод заканчивается. Вместо одной звездочки при вводе символа появляются две, в чем проблема?

```
char c{};

while ((c = _getch()) != 13)
{
    _putch('*');
}
```

Comment: *"Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему."*

Comment: Я хочу организовать ввод пароля, чтобы вместо символа в консоли появлялись звездочка, если нажата клавиша Enter ввод заканчивается. Вместо одной звездочки при вводе символа появляются две, в чем проблема?

Comment: Проверил ваш код, он нормально работает. Чем компилируете? Как запускаете?

Comment: Visual Studio 2017

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Да вот забавно... Под Open Watcom все нормально, а VC++ 2017 действительно делает повторное чтение символа 0 - но в документации об этом ничего нет...

Comment: @Harry у меня MinGW

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev
Попробовал что то поменять: 

while ((c = _getch()) != 13)
 {
  c = _getch();
  _putch('*');
 }

Так выводит одну звездочку, но после c = _getch(); значение из "c" куда то пропадает

Comment: В VC++ 2010 работает без проблем...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот так работает в Visual Studio 2017, зато не работает в других компиляторах

```
    #include "stdafx.h" 
    #include <iostream> 
    #include <string> 
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string s{};
        char c{};

        while ((c = _getch()) != 13)
        {
            _getch();
            s += c;
            _putch('*');
        }

        cout << endl << s <<  endl;

    return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Словом, как выяснилось, это [баг](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792349/getch-returns-2-characters-when-i-type-one). Который предлагают решать путем статической линковки с более старой версией рантайма C, но, понятно, что это метод, мягко говоря, очень невеселый.

Ждем обновлений Windows/Visual C++ с исправлением бага...

**Update**

VC++ 2017 15.8.7 - при компиляции с динамической библиотекой (`/MD`) работает нормально, при статической - нет...

**Update2**

Нормально работает при установке SDK версии 10.0.17763.0

Answer (score 0):

Раз метка `c++`, то используйте стандарт `c++`: [c++ ввод](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io), [c-style ввод в c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c). Там функций `_getch()` и `_putch()` нет.

Comment: В <conio.h> есть

Comment: @Герман вот список стандартных хедеров https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: Эк как вы лихо CRT зарубили, по-чапаевски, так сказать.

Comment: Увы, это не решение. И даже не обходной путь...

Answer (score 0):

Как говорится что посеяли, то и пожинаете...

Условие вашего цикла: вводить символ, сравнить с числом 13, если нет равенства, то выводить звездочку. Вы вводите символ, потом нажимете  `enter`, что является еще одним символом, потому и два раза выводится звездочка. 
Желаемый результат(чтобы выводить столько звездочек, сколько символов вводите, не учитывая пробел, можете получить так:

```
while ((c = getchar())  != 13 && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c == ' ')  continue;
         putchar('*');    
    }
```

Как видите, все нужно контролировать самим, так почему же не воспользоваться инструментами, предоставленными библиотекой?...

```
 while (std::cin >> c && c != 13)
         std::cout << '*' ;
```

Comment: Нет, на VC++ действительно после чтения символа происходит второе чтение нулевого значения. Т.е. при вводе 5 букв и Enter получается 11 звездочек...

Comment: Harry,  если вводите несколько значений, то читается и пробел тоже...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan если ввести `123456<Enter>` выдаст `*************`.

Comment: В предложенном мной варианте или в вашем?

Comment: У вас есть VC++ 2017? Скомпилируйте и посмотрите сами. Вот на такое `for(int c = _getch(); c != 13; c = _getch())
    {
        printf("%c[%d]\n",c,c);
    }` выводит при вводе Hello - `H[72]
 [0]
e[101]
 [0]
l[108]
 [0]
l[108]
 [0]
o[111]
 [0]`

Comment: В вашем варианте все хорошо - за одним исключением: вводимая строка оказывается видна на экране.

Comment: @Harry,  для начала нужно понять какой вид и результат нужен( я только указал причину вывода звездочек в неожидаемом количестве). Но лучше просто  не пользоваться старыми методами...