# Принцип работы функции getche()

Tags: c++

Программа должна посчитать количество символов и слов в введённой строке, считывание осуществляется при помощи функции getche().

Пример из учебника:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int chcount = 0;
    int wdcount = 1;
    char ch = 'a';
    cout << "Enter a phrase: ";
    while (ch != '\r')
    {
        ch = getche();
        if (ch == ' ')
            wdcount++;
        else
            chcount++;
    }
    cout << "\nWords=" << wdcount << endl
    << "Letters= " << (chcount - 1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод такой программы будет не правильным. Например: при строке "dfg" количество символов(chcount) будет равно 6, при строке "dfg dfg" кол-во символов будет 13.

> Функция getche() возвращает очередной символ, считанный с консоли, и выводит этот символ на экран.

Пошаманив с отладкой, предполагаю, что после вывода полученного символа на экран считывает его ещё раз, притом в виде "\0".

Windows. Visual Studio 2017.

Это связанно с принципом работы getche? VS? В более поздних версиях VS или новых стандартах C++ старая функция совсем ненормально работает?

Comment: Похоже, это все та же проблема, что описана [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892893/c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-getch-putch). Все никак не починят... :(

Comment: `getche` к стандартному C++ не имеет никакого отношения, так что от новых или старых стандартов ждать изменения в её поведении не стоит.

Comment: Заявленное поведение не воспроизводится. Во-первых этот код не собирается из-за `error C4996`, которая яростно подавляется. Во-вторых при строке "dfg" `chcount` будет равно 4, при строке "dfg dfg" кол-во символов будет 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написано [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/893028/316300) при компиляции с динамической библиотекой /MD функция getche() работает правильно в Visual Studio 2017.

Проект -> Свойства проекта -> Свойства конфигурации -> C/C++ -> Создание кода -> Библиотека времени выполнения -> Многопоточный DLL (/MD)
Не уверен что решает проблему полностью, но в данном примере getche() начинает работать корректно.